# unable to activate developer mode in odoo16 cause it not even showing up

Tags: python-3.x, odoo-15, odoo-16

I have two odoo servers in local host from one which odoo15 which running as root in localhost:8069. And I can't make any development modules cause it has folders with all locked files inside it and also showing settings as needed. And I followed this from this link {https://www.cybrosys.com/blog/how-to-install-odoo-16-on-ubuntu-2004-lts}
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/o0HZ9.png)

And I have another development odoo16 server which i want to run in localhost:8027. After many failing attempts I made the server open without any error but now when login into it and pressed to setting option it's only showing user and company option and unable to go back to all apps and also not showing developer mode to activate or any other things.I followed and setup it from this link{https://www.cybrosys.com/blog/odoo-16-development-environment-with-visual-studio-code-in-ubuntu-2004} I tried with many solutions from many blogs but none it's working also the databases and users of both the servers are also not alike. Can anyone please help me to sort this out cause I'm new to odoo platform.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mMfnD.png)

I tried to solve it by various ways and which I saw from other blogs and pages but still the same issue.Any help would be greatly appreciated

Comment: Please install any app. Then you will see the setting.

Comment: Thanks for your time and reply. I started the new server and install one app and it's showing now.